# Pass array into a stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass an array of values from php to mysql stored procedures as parameter list and how to use the array inside the stored procedure. The query in the procedure has three IN statements in in there so I would like to do `IN(@listOfids)` where @listOfids is 1,2,3,4 (an imploded array from php).

Comment: Could you post part of your code by editing your answer so that we might better understand what you are trying to achieve and work from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I got a workaround which is to concatenate the query and the parameters so the pseudo code is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `related_stories`(IN param1 VARCHAR(255), IN param2 VARCHAR(255), IN param3 VARCHAR(255), IN publishDate INT(11), IN tlimit INT(11))
BEGIN

SET  @query =CONCAT( '

select s.* from 
(

select * from 
(
 SELECT something where condition IN (',param1,')
) as table1

UNION ALL

select * from 
(
 SELECT something where condition IN (',param2,')
) as table2

UNION ALL

select * from 
(
 SELECT something where condition IN (',param3,')
) as table3

) as s

WHERE (s.publish_date < ',publishDate,') 
GROUP BY id limit ',tlimit,';');

PREPARE stmtInsert FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmtInsert;

END
```

param1,param2,param3 are imploded arrays that is passed in via php e.g.('1,2,3,4'). Hope this helps someone

Comment: @Akeem - if the above solution works for you, mark your answer as the acceptable answer so your question won't appear in the "unanswered" list anymore.

Comment: I tried but I got a message saying I have to wait 48 hours before accepting my own answer.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed in a pinch.  I think it is possible to dump the id list into a temp table but I will do that when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem here is that MySQL doesn't support arrays as a data type. You need to form a [one-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many) relationship to another table that contains a foreign key back to your main data and the array's data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass it in as a csv. Mysql is not very friendly with looping and such so your probably best doing it outside anyways. As far as stored procedure languages go I find Mysql really is lacking.