# procedure mysql not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, function, stored-procedures

```
$j = new DB();
$j->SetSqlCommnd("DELETE FROM cpd_colaborator_access
           WHERE col_cod = ".$_POST["colaborator"]."");
$j->Exec();



for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["page"]); $i++) 
{        
     $j = new DB();
     $j->SetSqlCommnd("INSERT INTO cpd_colaborator_access (access_id,col_cod)
                VALUES (".$_POST["page"][$i].",".$_POST["colaborator"].")");
     $j->Exec();  
}
```

I tried to represent this php code up, on this procedure below, passing an array as parameter "p_pages" and a id "p_colaborator";

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delegar_paginas`(
IN p_colaborator INT,
IN p_pages INT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE A INT(200);
DECLARE I INT(0);
IF (p_colaborator <> '') THEN
  DELETE FROM cpd_colaborator_access
  WHERE col_cod = p_colaborator;
  WHILE (I<@A) DO  
    IF(p_pages(0,I) <> '')THEN
      INSERT INTO cpd_colaborator_acess (acess_id,col_cod)
      VALUES (p_pages(0,I),p_colaborator);  
    ELSE
      SET I = A;
    END IF;
  END WHILE;
END IF;
END;
```

I am beginner to stored procedures, someone knows what may be wrong here ?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? We need to guess what **actuall** error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what datatypes p_colaborator and p_pages are supposed to be - you declare them both as INT in the parameter line, but you treat p_colaborator as a string, and p_pages as an array (of strings?), but it's inserted into an ID field.

MySQL doesn't support arrays in procedures, but there are lots of work arounds (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595371/pass-array-into-a-stored-procedure).

So, this procedure makes some assumptions:

- p_colaborator is a string (varchar(255)).
- p_pages is a comma-separated list of numbers (as in '1,2,3,4').

With those assumptions, this procedure should do the trick:

```
DROP PROCEDURE delegar_paginas;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE delegar_paginas(IN p_colaborator VARCHAR(255), IN p_pages VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
IF (p_colaborator <> '') THEN
  DELETE FROM cpd_colaborator_access WHERE col_cod = p_colaborator;
  SET @ins = CONCAT('(', REPLACE(p_pages, ',', CONCAT(', "', p_colaborator, '"), (')), ', ', p_colaborator, ')');
  SET @SQL = CONCAT('INSERT INTO cpd_colaborator_acess (acess_id,col_cod) VALUES ', @ins);
  SELECT @SQL;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END IF;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```