# Pass in variable length lists of foreign keys as arguments to a stored procedure via JDBC and then use the lists to insert rows into a table

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I need to construct a single transaction / stored procedure that takes in two lists of foreign keys and inserts new rows into a table from those foreign keys.

Specifically, I have a table that has order_ids and item_ids corresponding to the order.  I need to add to this table when orders are submitted.

To summarize in code, I would like to do:

```
DELIMITER ##
BEGIN
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE addOrder(IN itemIds VARCHAR(255), IN orderIds VARCHAR(255))
// ----- SQL Equivalent of -----
// for (int i = 0; i < itemIds.length; ++i)
// INSERT INTO Items_Ordered(item_id, order_id) VALUES(itemIds[i], order_ids[i]);
// -----------------------------
END ##
DELIMITER ;
```

So in Java, I could then just do something like:

```
String listOfItems = '1, 2, 6, 7, 8';
String listOfOrders = '2, 1, 99, 82, 7';
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareCall("CALL addOrder(" + listOfItems + ", " + listOfOrders + ")");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Any ideas?

EDIT #1:

I really, really, really don't like this hacky solution: [Pass array into a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595371/pass-array-into-a-stored-procedure)

EDIT #2:

Another solution I was thinking was to create a temporary table in the stored procedure with the input, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Do you HAVE to do it in a stored procedure? Have you considered doin the insert directly from Java ?

Comment: I am working on an Web Service / API that does not require knowing (hardly) anything about the underlying database it uses.  All it needs to know are the stored procedure names and the arguments they require.

So, do I HAVE to?  No.  Do I WANT to?  Yes, and for good reasons.

Comment: The design still seems flawed to me. If you do want to implement the "stored proc" model, create a procedure that inserts a single pair and then call that in a transaction multiple times. That way you can control and manage your negative test cases much better.

Comment: Consistency.  This is not the only thing that is happening in the procedure, but even if it was, all the items must be added at once or not at all.  Therefore it must all be done in one transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a string split function along these lines:

http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-split-delimited-string-into-rows

Then you can split your comma separated string into discreet values for insertion.

Comment: That might be feasible if I wasn't a MySQL noob.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Sweet, I found a good, simple string splitter here:

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/199134

Thanks for the advice...  I think I can solve it now.