# Is it possible to get list of collection as input in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to pass list of collection from php to mysql. For that what input parameter i have to set in mysql stored procedure. Please suggest your solution.For example: In sql we have user defined tables.any options in mysql?

Comment: Seems not possible to directly pass array to mysql stored procedure, you need to workaround and pass data as variables check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/596613/5452965

Comment: for example i have infinite array value how can i did?
In above sample they have 3 array only.Please suggest. I am new for mysql

Comment: Can you show us how your `array` looks like ? `print_r` maybe will clear the things, try `echo '<pre>' . print_r($yourArray, true) . '</pre>';` and post here some of the output

Comment: I have class.class having some properties like(name,subject,Total). I pass List<class>. How will pass to mysql SP

Comment: `List` are you sure? Do you mean `array`? If is list more sounds like **C#**. What is exactly the technology you are using? If C# and SQL server then you can define your own type as table,MySql doesn't support this, if you are using MySQL you should loop through your array and pass properties of you object as parameters to the stored procedure.

Comment: okay,i got the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share it ?

Comment: I just created one temp table in mysql . then insert the list of data in that table using for loop. Then get the data's through select query from that table.